# How can i fix pip?

Tags: python-3.x, import, pip

I've just upgraded python from version 3.10.8 to 3.11.3. And whenever I go to Command Prompts and typed : pip install,  it gives me an error saying: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\minhh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\minhh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" install pygame': The system cannot find the file specified.

I can use pip install by entering : python -m pip install but when I run python files it gives me:
'ImportError: cannot import name '*imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\minhh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL_*init**.py) ' like this :(
I had tried to edit PATH in Environment variables, delete all Python310 path, and add Python 311 path; but it didnt work :(
How can I fix this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems out of scope for StackOverflow, it does not seem really related to programming but rather related to system administration instead. -- Something probably went wrong, I would reinstall everything if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not like to comment on system point of view but I will suggest you to use stable versions of python eg. python 3.8.6. This will help in production environment  due to chances of getting interdependencies of various packages unworkable.